# Xcode 5.0 Doesn't Symbolicate Crash Log

Tags: ios, xcode5, symbolicatecrash

I have a submitted `iOS` app and I have the build archive with me. So, I took the crashes from `iTunesConnect` but when I tried to symbolicate them (dragged the `.crash` files to `Xcode Organizer` they didn't get symbolicated. I also pressed the `Symbolicate` button.

I am using `Xcode 5.0`, and I am pretty sure that the crashes that I am symbolicating came from the correct version of the build archive that I have.

Any ideas of why it doesn't work?

Thanks!

### EDIT

```
Incident Identifier: E2A64AF6-C8A3-465D-81C3-09674CD18771
Hardware Model:      iPhone4,1
Process:         MyApp [9551]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/0B0523C1-0EF9-41D8-AE91-D0C43B8DC00E/MyApp.app/MyApp
Identifier:      MyApp
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2013-09-17 16:42:10.390 -0500
OS Version:      iOS 6.1.3 (10B329)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xc2269d62
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3975f5b0 objc_msgSend + 16
1   MyApp                           0x00215812 0x100000 + 1136658
2   MyApp                           0x00216ca0 0x100000 + 1141920
3   MyApp                           0x001494e2 0x100000 + 300258
4   UIKit                           0x33898fb0 -[UIApplication _deactivateForReason:notify:] + 396
5   UIKit                           0x338cef26 -[UIApplication _handleApplicationSuspend:eventInfo:] + 310
6   UIKit                           0x338451e2 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 2454
7   UIKit                           0x338446c8 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 68
8   UIKit                           0x33844116 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6150
9   GraphicsServices                0x3555c5a0 _PurpleEventCallback + 588
10  GraphicsServices                0x3555c1ce PurpleEventCallback + 30
11  CoreFoundation                  0x31a11170 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 32
12  CoreFoundation                  0x31a11112 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 134
13  CoreFoundation                  0x31a0ff94 __CFRunLoopRun + 1380
14  CoreFoundation                  0x31982eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
15  CoreFoundation                  0x31982d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
16  GraphicsServices                0x3555b2e6 GSEventRunModal + 70
17  UIKit                           0x338982fc UIApplicationMain + 1116
18  MyApp                           0x00148b9a 0x100000 + 297882
19  MyApp                           0x001028f4 0x100000 + 10484
```

Here's one of the crashes.

Comment: Do you get any error messages? (look in `Console.app`).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Here's what the console says,

http://tinypic.com/m/fyo67r/3

Comment: I don't see any errors in those log entries.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any idea? By the way, I was using `Xcode 4.6` before and it was working then I installed `Xcode 5.0` without deleting and/or replacing the `Xcode 4.6`.

Comment: I think it must be a bug in Xcode 5.  There have been other questions about this knocking about.  You might have to use the command line (`lldb` or `atos`).

Comment: I tried `atos` and I believe that results were not accurate. Thanks for the help! :D

Comment: How about providing some more information like posting the crash report before and after so we know what is getting symbolicated and what is not. It is impossible to give an explanation without knowing what the actual issue is.

Comment: This is not the full crash report. Please post the full report if you want to get specific help.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had the same problem and for me it was due to the name I had given the Xcode application.

I was still working on production code in 4.6 when the GM version of 5 came out. Prior releases had DPn appended but the GM was called  "Xcode" so I renamed it to "Xcode 5". That space was my problem.

Looking in the console log and expanding **[symbolicatecrash] stderr:** I found the following line after it started looking for my app's symbols:

> sh: /Applications/Xcode: No such file or directory

Renaming the application to "Xcode5" and hitting re-symbolicate immediately symbolicated the crash log.

That may not be your exact problem but it's certainly worth expanding that stderr: section in the console log and looking for any errors related to fetching the symbol file for your app.

Comment: Same thing. You'd think spaces in names was a solved problem by now.

Comment: Where is the expandable stderr thing mentioned in the answer?

Comment: For me, this was not the issue. This solved it for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20715303/how-can-i-tell-spotlight-to-index-my-dsym-bundles (final solution, i.e. move Archives out of Library)

Comment: The same problem and solution.

Answer (score 0):

In my case checking the consol log for [symbolicatecrash] stderr showed nothing specific.  I restarted Xcode and checked the consol for error entries generated by Xcode.  There were several entries mentioning problems with the keychain.  One of my certificates was missing.

I requested new certificates from Xcode by going to:
Preferences>Accounts>View Details

Xcode detected there was a missing certificate and provided the option to submit a request.  After going through that process, Xcode was able to re-symbolicate from the Organizer Window as expected.

Comment: What if I don't have any accounts?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your Xcode application name doesn't contain any spaces. This was the reason it didn't work for me. So `/Applications/Xcode.app` works, while `/Applications/Xcode 6.1.1.app` doesn't work.